# Should I follow Mac or Windows UI guidelines?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, usability-testing, users

In my product am using a modeless dialog box with “OK” and “Minimize” button. Where I can place these buttons on the Top Left or Top Right? If I place on the Top Left it shows am focused only on the Mac Users. Is there any standards?

[image]

Comment: Are you developing a Windows or Mac application?

Comment: Not application. Browser based cloud product.

Comment: Do you even need minimise and close buttons on a modal dialog? A lot of web dialogs I see simply have the options, okay and cancel etc. Convention is that the close is a cancel, but that's not aways the case. Removing them completely reduces ambiguity. If you need to minimize it doesn't help though! If you're using a minimisable dialog, it could be that you shouldn't be using one at all though... (what does minimise mean on a web app anyway?)

Answer (score 2):

The browser is a platform agnostic environment. You don't have to follow OS convention (although it would definitely aid UX if it did).

Saying that though, you can't beat a bit of convention! Looking at some frameworks and examples, they generally follow the Windows way.

Here's a jQuery UI dialogue for example:

[image]

Also, doing a good ol' google search for [javascript modal dialogue](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%20modal%20dialog&espv=2&biw=1745&bih=868&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvjp3Wvc_NAhVHKMAKHQa9DyAQ_AUIBigB) returns a page where nearly every example has the <kbd>X</kbd> button at the top right (the others have the <kbd>X</kbd> button as a call-to-action beneath the modal's content like <kbd>Ok</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd>).

## However...

...if it was really important to you, you could sniff the OS using JavaScript using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript); then set a class on the modal of `controlAlignment-mac` or `controlAlignment-windows` and then float them left or right accordingly, that way you get the best of both worlds.

## Personally...

...I think users are savvy enough to scan for the controls necessary to dismiss a dialogue as the <kbd>X</kbd> is pretty generic and easy to spot so I would just stick to the convention.